# "Ajax is not found" exception - is Rails defaulting to Prototype by mistake?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to create a page that shows a list of tasks and allows the user to update task status by checking a checkbox.

When I run the page on the browser and click on the checkbox, I get a Javascript Exception "

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Ajax is not
>   defined (anonymous function)2:96
>   onclick

Here is the code that I have on my _task.html.erb file:

```
<%= check_box_tag "id", "id", task.done, 
    :onclick => remote_function(
      :update => "task", 
      :url => { :action => :update }, 
      :with => "'done=true'", 
      :complete => "alert('hi')"  ) %>
```

Why am I getting this *Ajax is not defined* exception?

I reinstalled rails jquery, ensure that there is a rails.js and a jquery.js in the javascripts folder and confirmed they are loading on the HTML, see below:

```
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.js?1303396383" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/rails.js?1303562965" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/application.js?1301606933" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.purr.js?1302145859" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/best_in_place.js?1302150372" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Someone posted a comment saying that "Ajax" with capital A is a prototype function rather than a rails function. Is my application somehow configured to try to use Prototype rather than rails? While files do I need to change to fix this?

I just tried changing config/application.rb and uncommented this line:

```
config.action_view.javascript_expansions[:defaults] = %w(jquery rails)
```

Didn't seem to work either. Any idea?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`remote_function`, like most of RJS, [uses Prototype directly](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper.html) and is not part of the UJS concept. The Prototype helpers are always available in a Rails application (until Rails 3.1), but the JavaScript they produce is Prototype-only and will not work unless you are also using the Prototype JavaScript library.

In your example, you are using jQuery and not Prototype. If you want to use jQuery, you should write out the expected JavaScript or write your own `remote_function` helper.

Comment: You are right. I added prototype.js and it started working. Will upgrade to rails 3.1 as soon as it is stable.

Comment: To clarify, Rails 3.1 will make jQuery the default. I imagine it would also move the Prototype helpers (the `ActionView::Helpers::PrototypeHelper` module) into a separate gem. If you want to use the Prototype helpers such as `remote_function`, you will have to take extra steps to use Prototype in Rails 3.1. You also have the option of looking at the `remote_function` source code and writing something similar that works on top of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're not including the default javascript libraries.  Take a look in your layout file, and you need a line like this up in the head (I'm assuming ERB):

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

And make sure either prototype or jquery exists in `public/javascripts` and the `rails.js` too.

#### Update

You revealed in a comment that you're using jquery - but your error mentions a capital-a "Ajax" which is the prototype name.

To get the right rails.js [follow these instructions](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs)

Comment: I am including everything and all files are in the JS folder.  <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-1.4.4.min", "rails", "jquery.purr", "best_in_place", "application" %>

Comment: I added the line in your answer to the one I already had, it didn't work. Here is the content of my javascripts folder: application.js, best_in_place.js, controls.js, dragdrop.js, effects.js, jquery-1.4.4.min.js, jquery.purr.js, prototype.js and rails.js

Comment: I did the changes to Gemfile as explained in your link, ran bundle install and then ran: 
$ rails generate jquery:install. I continue getting the same error and it continues to be with a capital A. Any ideas?

Comment: These are all my JS includes:  <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-1.4.4.min", "rails", "jquery.purr", "best_in_place", "application" %>
 
 
 <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>

Comment: The problem is in the `rails.js` file, it's still the prototype one, the jquery-ujs process works, but sometimes fails because of SSL in github.  Use the manual process.

Comment: One way or the other, you need to replace your `rails.js` file with the jquery one.  The right `rails.js` file starts with `jQuery(`

Comment: I checked my rails.js file and it is exactly like what I saw on https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js